# split a video with overlap between segments

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I need to split a video into a sequence of segments like the following: (numbers are mm:ss) 00:00 to 03:05, 03:00 to 06:05, 06:00 to 09:05, etc. In other words, each segment will have 5 seconds of overlap with the following segment. The purpose of this is for a transcription program. Each 3 minute segment will be transcribed separately. The 5 seconds of overlap will help in stitching the transcribed text segments back together.

Do I need to extract each 3 minute and 5 second segment separately? For example, by doing the following:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -i in.mp4 -t 00:06:05 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -y out.mp4
```

Or is there a way to do all the segments in one pass?

[ Project is: [Govmeeting](https://github.com/govmeeting/govmeeting) ]

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg has a segment muxer which can segment the file in one command but it does not create overlapping segments so not suitable here.

You'll have to run individual commands, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:03:00 -t 00:03:10 -i in.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero out-300.mp4
```

Since you're copying the streams, the segments likely won't start at the exact start points. So, I've increased the duration a bit to accommodate that and also make sure timestamps start at zero, as not all players correctly handle playback of MP4s with negative timestamps. Negative timestamps would have occurred normally, if the file split point was not a keyframe.

Comment: I understand the video may not start at the exact point. But will the audio always start and end where specified? [ PS: I found your explanation of splitting a video on superuser.com. Very helpful. ]

Comment: Yes, audio will start where specified if negative timestamps are allowed. If not, like above, then the audio starts from where the video starts.